# Force Word to write a read-only file

Tags: networking, microsoft-word

I opened a file on a network folder, suspended my computer and when I came back the file was re-opened read-only because of some esoteric Windows-networking glitches occurred and word tried to be smart (the file is not read-only word just re-opened it so). So I had to save it under another name. Then I had to go to the folder, find the file, delete it and rename it again.

Is there any way to force Word to write to this file anyway? I don't care if it is some weird VBA hack but it is very annoying that Word always screws this up. I have this problem with no other program. Just word that tries to be more intelligent them other programs.

Answer (score 2):

Word is so magic... If file is read-only, it's read-only, you cannot write to it. Change file permissions to make it writable again:

Right-click -> Properties -> Uncheck "Read-only" (Windows XP)

Comment: Sorry that I did not made this clear in my original Post. The file is by no means read-only. Word just re-opened it read only because of some windows-network stuff that fails.